# Bi-directionnal asynchrone communication between app server and LoRaWAN-based sensor network

Tags: protocols, lorawan

I am trying to build a LoRaWAN-based sensor network. These sensors communicate their data through the LoRaWAN protocol to the gateway which forwards these data to an application server through the MQTT protocol and in the other way around.

The communication has to be done from the sensors to the server and from the server to the sensors. However, things get tough at the gateway level since the message from the sensors to the server and the message from the server to the sensors can arrive at any time and my LoRaWAN module (the RN2483 from Microchip) cannot be on listening and sending mode at the same time. Hence, if I try to forward the message from the server to the sensors, the LoRaWAN packet sent by the sensors will be lost.

Do you have protocol ideas or literature suggestion for efficiently sharing the LoRaWAN module between listening and sending mode?

Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to read **LoRaWAN specification** carefully. The LoRaWAN (not LoRa P2P model) has 3 types device, class A, B and C. RN2483 is one of class A devices, it will always have 2 receive windows (RX1, RX2) which last for 1 second long each after sending the message to gateway (uplink). You may use this feature to schedule your downlink messages. And the LoRaWAN server and LoRaWAN app server will handle the downlink issue (e.g., when to send downlink, immediately or one by one).